# What does "continuous" mean on functions over the rationals?

Tags: calculus, rational-numbers

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vV7ZuouUSfs) explores the possibility of defining calculus over the rational numbers.

He glosses over the definitions of "continuous". For example 13 minutes in he has

> $f(x)=x^2-2$
>
> Note: $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]\cap\mathbb{Q}$

In fact, he opens with a definition

> Recall: a function $f$ is continuous at a if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$

and then immediately gives an example of how this *doesn't* work on rationals. But then goes on to use "continuous" in his exploration anyway.

What does "continuous" mean in the context of rational numbers? Is he just exploring nonsense statements?

Comment: watch carefully. He does not say that the concept of continuity doesn't work on the rational, he just says that it intuitively works differently from the real numbers

Comment: Why would there be a problem with defining continuity?  Just use the usual definition restricting the variables to rationals.

Answer (score 1):

The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit, and of continuity, make sense in the rationals.  Many (but not all) of the proofs you may see about limits and continuity in your calculus course, make sense in any ordered field.

More generally (as you may learn in the future) they make sense in any "metric space".